# VB.NET Startup Form Won't Change

Tags: vb.net, winforms, startup

I have 4 forms in my application, and of course, Form1 loads first. I went into the Application Properties and changed the startup form to Form4, which I want as the startup form. For some reason, Form1 always is still coming up first for some reason.
Please help.

Comment: You did save the changes and rebuild the solution after making the change, right?